# How to Replace String In File With Double Quotes

Tags: c#

want to Replace Text in My File strText @Insurer with XYZ
output be like this "XYZ"

till now i do this

```
strText.Replace("@Insurer",XYZ)
```

this gives me XYZ but not this "XYZ"

so i did this

```
strText.Replace("\"@Insurer\"",XYZ)
```

but it didn't replace my String with XYZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inorder to replace with quotes you can try using backward slash (`"\"`). The example below shows how to implement.

```
public string ReplaceString(string strText)
{
   string replaceWith = "\"XYZ\"";
   string replacedString = strText.Replace("@Insurer", replaceWith);
   return replacedString;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the text *after* the replacement to be quoted, then you should put the replacement string in quotes:

```
strText.Replace("@Insurer", "\"" + XYZ + "\"")
```

Otherwise, you would be searching for the literal string `"@Insurer"` and just replace it by `XYZ`. So if there were quotes (which likely isn’t the case, otherwise you wouldn’t want to add them), then this would actually remove them.

Answer (score 1):

Add double quote around xyz. You have to escape the double quotes for that you use escape character i.e. backslash `\`. Also you are not assigning the resultant  string back to strText and wont get the changed string.

```
strText = strText.Replace("@Insurer", "\"" + XYZ + "\"");
```

The second attempt that failed to replace is because you have added double quotes in string that you are trying to find and there are not double quotes in source string.